# What is the django equivalent of this SQL query?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am very new to django and I am tryin to accomplish some repetitive tasks. I was wondering what would be the django equivalent of the following tasks.

1. I want to select all values that fall within a certain date range.

Eg: Let there be a table called exam scores

```
 User Physics  Chemistry Mathematics Total  Date
 bill    98       94          Pass    284   02/03/2013
 murray  0        89          Fail     89   02/03/2013
 bill    10       20          Pass     90   01/29/2013
```

Now assume I want to write a django command that obtains user bill's object for all cases where he has passed in mathematics.

here I would write something like

```
scores = Score.objects.filter(user = "bill", Mathematics = "pass")
```

The problem with the above code is when i do something like

```
 for s in scores:
     print "Physics score =", s.Physics
```

the control never comes to the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you are asking for something like this

```
math_scores = Score.objects.filter(user='bill', date__range=(timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=7), timezone.now()).values_list('mathematics', flat=True)
```

which will give you all math scores for bill in the past week as a list like

```
[92, 60]
```

Is this what you are looking to do or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: it is somewhat right but I am looking to obtain all objects with the value in mathematics. Say I should be able to see bill's physics scores by accessing the object which satisfies the condition. Also your query gave me a syntax error

Comment: I changed my question a bit. Can you please take a look and help me fix what might be wrong?

Comment: @appyg What do you mean by "the control never comes to the print statement." because I don't see anything wrong with the logic you have in your question.

Comment: when I run the program even though there are entries that match the criteria, scores variable is empty instead of having the list of objects which match the particular criteria

Comment: @appyg Can you add the actual view that you are using and the actual score model?

Answer (score 0):

Given the data and query you show above, there *are* no elements matching 'bill' and 'pass'. There are elements matching 'bill' and 'Pass', which is a different thing.

I don't understand the relevance of your point about date ranges, though.